# Bootstrap carousel with thumbnails with php thumbnail isnt working PHP

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with my thumbs,when i click on them it does not have any effect on my carousel. my carousel works only the next and prev buttons. What i want to do is,when i click in my thumbnail it changes the pic inside of the carousel.
the first pic of my thumbs has an id="carousel-selector-0"
and in my carousel is data-slide-number="0"
but this isnt working and i want to load the rows that has 7 images in each column in my db... see my db pic--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gu9a.jpg
this is my whole code ---> https://codeshare.io/yiGrk

---

```
<?php
 //$g_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['id']));
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
            $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){

                echo' 





<div class="modal fade" id="info'.$rows['id'].'" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">'.$rows['title'].'</h3>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        <!--<div class="row">




<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider / Carousel</h1>


    <!-- thumb navigation carousel -->
    <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs'.$rows['id'].'">

            <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
          <ul class="list-inline">

          <li class="col-sm-2" > 
          <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../'.$rows['image'].'"></a></li>

           <li class="col-sm-2" > 
          <a id="carousel-selector-1" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../'.$rows['img_v1'].'"></a></li>

          <li class="col-sm-2"> <a id="carousel-selector-2"  class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../'.$rows['img_v2'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>

          <li class="col-sm-2"> <a id="carousel-selector-3"  class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../'.$rows['img_v3'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>

                <li class="col-sm-2"> <a id="carousel-selector-4"  class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../'.$rows['img_v4'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>

          <li class="col-sm-2"> <a id="carousel-selector-5"  class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>

          <!--<li> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
            <img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>

          <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
            <img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>

           <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
            <img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" class="img-responsive">
          </a></li>--->
            </ul>

    </div>


    <!-- main slider carousel -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">

                <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                    <div id="myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" class="carousel slide">
                        <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                <img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" class="img-responsive" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                              <img src="../'.$rows['img_v1'].'" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                <img src="../'.$rows['img_v2'].'" " class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                <img src=""../'.$rows['img_v3'].'" " class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                <img src=""../'.$rows['img_v4'].'" " class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> 

                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel'.$rows['id'].'" data-slide="next">›</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/main slider carousel-->

</div>





<!--------------------------slider------------------------------->

                        <!--</div><!-- /.row below modal body-->
                </div><!-- /.modal-body--->
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div><!-- /.modal-dialog  -->
</div>


 ';} ?> 
<script>


 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
  var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sidenote: If and when you ever comment out `//$g_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['id']));` that function requires a db connection be passed to it. RTM on it. We also don't know if you (successfully) connected to the db or not with the same API. Check for errors and view your console.

Comment: i took of that comment.and i am connected no errors

Comment: the problem is the **carousel-selector-0** that doesnt work

Comment: i tried this carousel-selector-'.$rows['image'].' and the **data-slide-number="'.$rows['image'].'"** and it didnt work either